# How to paginate data with Omines dataTable symfony 5

Tags: javascript, symfony, datatable, orm

I try to paginate 2 millions of data using **the bundle Omines dataTable with symfony 5**, but the answer still the same, the bundle return me all data in database instead of the limited i asked.

As you can see, in the query builder, i use limit and maxResults criteria like in a full doctrine to get only 200 000 data, but the result still return all the data that are in the database. And curiously, when i do a die and dump to `$paginator->getIterator()`, it show me the asked and paginated data.
It can be that i don't know how to use Doctrine Paginator with Omines DataTable bundle in symfony 5, so it will be helpful if someone can help me

My code in symfony controller

```
        ->createAdapter(
            ORMAdapter::class,
            [
                'entity' => ReportOmPaiement::class,
                'query' => [
                    function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
                        $limit = 200000;
                        $query =
                        $builder->select('c')
                        ->from(ReportOmPaiement::class, 'c')
                        ->leftJoin('c.Company', 'com')
                        ->leftJoin('c.Client', 'client')
                        ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');
                        $paginator = new Paginator($query, true);
                        $paginator
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->setFirstResult(0)
                        ->setMaxResults($limit);
                        $lasPage = (int) ceil($paginator->count() / $paginator->getQuery()->getMaxResults());
                        $paginator->getIterator();
                    }
                ]
            ]
        )
```

And the render in the inspected view [image: the console of return]

Answer (score 0):

in my previous answer we have been calling **$paginator->count()** before retrieving the paginated data. This can cause the paginator to load all the data instead of the limited subset. **$paginator->count()** before retrieving the paginated data. and i guess this can cause the paginator to load all the data instead of the limited subset.

```
->createAdapter(
ORMAdapter::class,
[
    'entity' => ReportOmPaiement::class,
    'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
        $limit = 200000;
        $query = $builder
            ->select('c')
            ->from(ReportOmPaiement::class, 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c.company', 'com')
            ->leftJoin('c.client', 'client')
            ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');

        //a separate query to count the total number of records
        $countQuery = clone $query;
        $countQuery->resetDQLPart('orderBy');
        $countQuery->select('COUNT(c.id)');

        $paginator = new Paginator($query, true);
        $paginator
            ->getQuery()
            ->setFirstResult(0)
            ->setMaxResults($limit);

        //paginated data here
        $data = $paginator->getIterator();

        //total count here
        $totalRecords = (int) $countQuery->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
        $lastPage = (int) ceil($totalRecords / $limit);

        return $data;
    },
]
```

);

If am right, by retrieving the paginated data before calling $paginator->count(), you should get the expected result of only having the limited subset of data instead of all the data from the database.

Comment: Thanks @Chafik Kerboute but the result seem the same! The adapter still return all the data in database! Any other idea ?

Comment: check the updated answer i guess it might work for you if am not wrong !

Comment: "*in my previous answer*", euh...!?, which "*previous answer*"...!? Answers (and Questions) should be self-contained... Provide at least a Link to that "previous Answer/Thread"...

Comment: You seem to be calling the previous revision of your answer as "my previous answer", although we do have a revision history this makes your answer hard to understand since you seem to be focusing on your previous answers mistake more rather than on solving the question, please [edit] your answer so that it reads more naturally. cc @chivracq

Comment: Oh!, Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat for the Ping, as all Answers from this User are being "scrutinized" a little bit (['Meta' Thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425562/3799241)), I didn't even think of checking any previous Revision... // But like I said, any Answer should be "Self-Contained"...

Comment: @chafik-kerboute The result still the same unfortunately !